# how to use js code provided on github in my project

Tags: angularjs, github, import

I am new to angular js. I got google-diff-match library(js code) on github and now I want to use it in my project how do i use it? As a java developer i can download the jar and use it by importing it. How should I do it for angular js.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an angular wrapper to use it for angular projects. There is an existing library for the same:

https://github.com/amweiss/angular-diff-match-patch

npm and bower install options are mentioned in the link. If you want to use it directly, you can refer this codepen link in the page:

https://codepen.io/amweiss/pen/grXNPm

Refer the files referenced in the HTML and then include below in your dependencies:

```
var app = angular.module('diffDemo', ['ngMaterial', 'diff-match-patch']);
```

Comment: Thanks but still I am not clear how should I download this wrapper library present on https://github.com/amweiss/angular-diff-match-patch. And where i write <script src="">(CDN for google diff).

Comment: Please look at the codepen above. It should have the complete code with all the CDN links referenced in HTML.

Comment: Code is working but I need old object and new object as shown in http://agiliq.com/blog/2014/05/google-diff-match-patch-library/ which is not provided in codepen